# Python 3.9.12 AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'DETACHED_PROCESS'

Tags: python, subprocess

Please help understand why `DETACHED_PROCESS` is not available in 3.9.2.

```
--> 594 subprocess.call(process, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)

AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'DETACHED_PROCESS'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS) has it.

> subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
> A Popen creationflags parameter to specify that a new process will not inherit its > parent’s console. This value cannot be used with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE.

### Environment

MacOS 12.4.
Python version is 3.9.12.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
-----
3.9.12
```

Comment: Did you see that the section is called "**Windows** Constants"? Could have been documentsed clearer though.

Comment: @KlausD Seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @mon Please don't edit answers into questions. I've added a community wiki answer referencing Klaus's comment.

Answer (score 1):

As [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) pointed out in the comments, `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` is listed among [constants only available on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants).